# Angular2: how to create custom validator for FormGroup?

Tags: validation, angular, angular2-forms, custom-validators, angular2-formbuilder

i'm creating a form with `FormBuilder` and i want to add a `Validator` to a `formGroup`.
Here is my code:

```
    this.myForm = fb.group({
        'name': ['', [Validators.maxLength(50), Validators.required]],
        'surname': ['', [Validators.maxLength(50), Validators.required]],
        'address': fb.group({
                'street': ['', Validators.maxLength(300)],
                'place': [''],
                'postalcode': ['']
        }),
        'phone': ['', [Validators.maxLength(25), phoneValidator]],
        'email': ['', emailValidator]
    });
```

I would like to conditionally add validators to some of the address's formControls on certain conditions.

So I added a `validator` in the following way:

```
        'address': fb.group({
                'street': ['', Validators.maxLength(300)],
                'place': [''],
                'postalcode': ['']
         }), { validator: fullAddressValidator })
```

Then i started to create a validator for the address `FormGroup`:

```
export const fullAddressValidator = (control:FormGroup) => {
    var street:FormControl = control.controls.street;
    var place:FormControl = control.controls.place;
    var postalcode:FormControl = control.controls.postalcode;

    if (my conditions are ok) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return { valid: false };
    }
};
```

I need to add the following conditions:

1. If all fields are empty the form is valid
2. If one of the field are filled in then all the fields must be required
3. If `place` is instance of country (instead of city) the `postalcode`
   is optional
4. If the `postalcode` is filled in then the `zipValidator` must be
   added to its formControl

So, it is possible to add Angular2 `Validators` to a `FormGroup` on certain conditions?
If it does, how to implement my conditions? Can i use `setValidators()` and `updateValueAndValidity()` in the source code of another validator?

Answer (score 2):

Create a function that takes a parameter and returns a validator function

```
export const fullAddressValidator = (condition) => (control:FormGroup) => {
    var street:FormControl = control.controls.street;
    var place:FormControl = control.controls.place;
    var postalcode:FormControl = control.controls.postalcode;

    if (my conditions are ok) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return { valid: false };
    }
};
```

and use it like

```
   'address': fb.group({
            'street': ['', Validators.maxLength(300)],
            'place': [''],
            'postalcode': ['']
     }), { validator: () => fullAddressValidator(condition) })
```

Comment: What should i pass as parameter?

Comment: The condition. The condition can be a value, a method of the component or a class instance or a function. You can use it inside the validator to do additional checks that have access to a scope outside the validator. If you pass a method, the method can access the components state at the time of the validation check. Ensure you use `()=>` arrow function syntax when you pass methods or functions around.

Comment: I'm currently have the whole `FormGroup` in my custom validator, so all conditions can be checked on its `FormControl`s. Am i wrong?

Comment: I haven't found a way to get the dirty state from `FormGroup`. But you can use my approach to get it from the outside. I think subscribing to `statusChanges` from the group or controls provides that info. I wouldn't expect this to work with the `FormGroup` passed to the validator by Angular because it might be marked dirty before the validator is called.

Comment: Why do you want the `dirty` state? Do you know how can i add validators to `formControl` in my custom validator?

Comment: Sorry! Seems I mixed something up with another question. My concentration is quite bad today, probably because of the construction site noise outside our building :-/

Comment: So the answer is, that you can't add validators depending on conditions but you can build the validators in a way that they consider outside conditions. You can add validators to a group but I don't think you can mark single controls inside the group invalid using a group validator. I think you would need to use my above approach and pass in the FormGroup to each field validator, so they can do validation depending on siblings status

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer can i pass FormGroup as a condition parameter, actually i have two sibling FormGroup and both are belonging to same parent FormGroup

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to set `FormControl` validators inside a `FormGroup` custom validator. Here is the solution to my needs:

```
export const fullAddressValidator = (control:FormGroup):any => {
    var street:FormControl = control.controls.street;
    var place:FormControl = control.controls.place;
    var postalcode:FormControl = control.controls.postalcode;

    if (!street.value && !place.value && !postalcode.value) {
        street.setValidators(null);
        street.updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf: true});
        place.setValidators(null);
        place.updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf: true});
        postalcode.setValidators(null);
        postalcode.updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf: true});

        return null;
    } else {
        street.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(300)]);
        street.updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf: true});
        place.setValidators([Validators.required]);
        place.updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf: true});
        if (place.value instanceof Country) {
            postalcode.setValidators(Validators.maxLength(5));
            postalcode.updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf: true});
        } else {
            postalcode.setValidators([zipValidator()]);
            postalcode.updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf: true});
        }
    }

    if (street.invalid || place.invalid || postalcode.invalid) {
        return {valid: false};

    } else {
        return null;
    }
};
```